# When navigate to new screen it's append to current screen on react-navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

when i navigate to new screen it's append to same screen, like this. react-navigataion v6 on web

[image]

what's wrong with it?

Linking and Routes
[image]

code is in there, can't post code on that post. it's getting error

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/discussions/10128

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Home/>` route is at '/' path, and **every other path ( /about, /details... ) will match the '/' path.**

---

### That is why `<Home/>` is on every other page you visit.

---

You can try to pass ***EXACT*** prop:

```
             <Sky.Screen
                    exact
                    key={index}
                    name={route.name}
                    component={route.screen}
                    initialParams={route.initialParams}
                    options={route.options}
              />
```

Then, React Router, instead of checking `componentCnfiguredPath.includes(currentPath) ? <ComponentConfigured/> : null`

will check if `componentCnfiguredPath====currentPath ? <ComponentConfigured/> : null`

Comment: bro this is not a react router. this is react-navigation v6